# No clue with an exception (NullPointerException) due to a properties retrieval thrown by the IBM MQ

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, nullpointerexception, ibm-mq

I'm having this exception thrown by the IBM MQ which I'm struggling with, I have no clue why this is happening. Here it comes:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getVersionProperty(JmqiEnvironment.java:2204)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getProductIdentifier(JmqiEnvironment.java:2224)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnection.initSess(RemoteConnection.java:1388)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:1078)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnectionPool.getConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:338)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1488)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.MQCONNX_j(MQSESSION.java:915)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:224)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:505)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:547)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:95)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:182)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:869)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:761)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:712)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:171)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.(init)(MQQueueManager.java:597)
    at mytestpackage.MyTestClass.(init)(MyTestClass.java:143)
    . . .
```

I'm having two scenarios, (1) A stand-alone one-threaded app which runs okay (jre6), but I'm having troubles when I use this (2) as part of a library used by a multi-core environment (using the 1.4.2 JVM).

#### Reproduced Code

```
MQEnvironment.hostname = Host;
MQEnvironment.channel = Channel;
MQEnvironment.port = Port;
MQEnvironment.userID = QMUser;
MQEnvironment.password = QMPass;

MQQueueManager qmanager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManager);
MQMessage mqmessage = new MQMessage();
MQPutMessageOptions mqputmessageoptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
MQQueue mqqueue = qmanager.accessQueue(QueueReq, 8208, null, null, null);

mqmessage.format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
mqmessage.persistence = 1;
mqmessage.replyToQueueName = QueueResp;
mqmessage.expiry = -1;
mqmessage.priority = -1;
mqmessage.writeString(MWAS);
mqmessage.messageId = "".getBytes();
mqmessage.correlationId = "".getBytes();

mqqueue.put(mqmessage, mqputmessageoptions);

mqqueue.close();
```

The execution doesn't even get to the instantiation of the `MQQueueManager`, the exception is thrown when assigning the `MQEnvironment`'s static attributes.

#### Extra Info

The running OS is Windows 2003 Server R2 Enterprise SP2 (x64). The JVM is the Sun's 1.4.2_10 (x86). The WMQ version is 7.0.1.5.
Some system properties are:
**java.runtime.version=1.4.2_10-b03**, **java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.**, **os.arch=x86**.

#### Deepest Exception

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.cssystem.WASSupport.<clinit>(WASSupport.java:39)
    at com.ibm.mq.internal.MQCommonServices$6.run(MQCommonServices.java:1263)
    at com.ibm.mq.internal.MQCommonServices$Helper.runIgnoresNoClass(MQCommonServices.java:1322)
    at com.ibm.mq.internal.MQCommonServices.isJmsCommonServicesRequired(MQCommonServices.java:1277)
    at com.ibm.mq.internal.MQCommonServices.<clinit>(MQCommonServices.java:265)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.getJmqiEnv(MQSESSION.java:134)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.<init>(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:93)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.<clinit>(MQEnvironment.java:574)
    at mytestpackage.MyTestClass.(init)(MyTestClass.java:143)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.logging.LoggingPermission control)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.checkAccess(LogManager.java:930)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.checkAccess(Logger.java:255)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.setLevel(Logger.java:1131)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.trace.DefaultTracer$8.run(DefaultTracer.java:1581)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.trace.DefaultTracer.setTraceLevel(DefaultTracer.java:1578)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.setTraceLevel(Trace.java:408)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.initialize(Trace.java:2027)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.<clinit>(Trace.java:323)
    ... 17 more
```

What could this be?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could we see some code? (like the line 143 of your class)

Comment: Can't, it's confidential, I don't even have it. Sorry.

Comment: Did you install the full MQ client or did you just grab the jar files?  And if your code that is calling MQ is confidential, can you reproduce the problem with some sample code and share that?

Comment: I did install the full WMQ, and installed the last fixpack (7.0.1.5), I appended the reproduced code as an edit of the main question.

Comment: I think it's worth to add that due to classpath issues I copied all the .jars from the /lib folder of the well-installed WMQ to the jre's /lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by the "the 1.1.0 MS JVM"? I can see from the stack trace that you're using the v7 MQ client - the JVM requirements are listed here

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27011920

Assuming you're 32-bit, the supported options are

```
Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition (J2SE) V1.4.2 from Sun Microsystems, Inc. 
Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition V5.0 (SR1 or above) from Sun Microsystems, Inc. 
Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition V6.0 from Sun Microsystems, Inc. 
IBM 32-bit SDK for Windows, Java 2 Technology Edition, V1.4.2 
IBM 32-bit SDK for Windows, Java 2 Technology Edition, V5.0 (SR1 or above) 
IBM 32-bit SDK for Windows, Java Technology Edition, V6.0
```

So I suspect that the code is throwing a NullPointerException because an unsupported JVM is unexpectedly returning null when the WMQ Java client is querying a system property.

Comment: The running OS is Windows 2003 Server R2 Enterprise SP2 (x64), but the JVM is the Sun's 1.4.2_10 (x86). I append some system properties: **java.runtime.version=1.4.2_10-b03**, **java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.**, **os.arch=x86**.

Comment: What do you think it could be?

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect T-Rob's comment is relevant. The top two lines of stack trace suggest it's querying the level of WMQ (i.e. breaking down "7.0.1.5" or similar) and for some reason is failing to obtain the required information. If you haven't already done so, i'd suggest upgrading to a clean install of the latest fixpac. It should also be trivial to recreate with a few lines of Java, as the stack trace is from initialization of a base Java QueueManager object and initial stages of a client-mode connection to WMQ

Comment: One more thought, I suspect it is trying to get information that is stored in the manifest of one of the .jar files - have you unpacked the .jars, changes the standard install in any way, or are you running with security manager settings that would prevent you from loading a .properties file?

Comment: I just edited the original question and appended the code. I installed the 7.0.1.5 fixpack as well. I'm having consideration of that suspicion related to the secyruty manager, since I remember I had troubles with accessing a file from my WMQ wrapper object, the problem was a FileNotFoundException being the path correct! Maybe I'm wrong with that.

Comment: strmqm, you were right, security manager problems, I appeneded a new exception I catched. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this happens, when you try to access a data structure [which is not synchronized inside] with multiple threads without a lock.

One of the object you are accessing in the stack trace is not multi threadble and you need a lock.

One example being HashMap [as against hashtable] - try to use it with multiple threads without a lock outside.

Comment: I made the code synchronized at the WMQ wrapper object and also at the MQEnvironment.class, since it uses statics attributes, but no, it keeps doing the same thing.